# Are questions related to using wolfram alpha on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is asking how to use wolfram alpha to solve an abstract algebra question on topic here?

Comment: [mathematica.stackexchange questions tagged "Wolfram Alpha"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha-queries)

Comment: I think if your question is maths-based, then fine. However, if your question is simply "how do I do a loop?" then...no.

Comment: @user1729 Your point is well taken - while many use WolframAlpha for mathematics, its scope is much more broad than that. WolframAlpha is not a programming language, however, so "how do I do a loop" isn't a particularly natural example. On the other hand, something like [digital cameras under $400](http://goo.gl/Oqk5V8) would clearly be off topic.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 The "WolframAlpha" tag at mathematica.se actually refers *only* to use of Mathematica's `WolframAlpha` command. For example, a question dealing with how to extract and manipulate data obtained from the `WolframAlpha` command directly within Mathematica would be considered on topic there. Questions specific to use of the web site are typically treated with great disdain on mathematica.se.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. I would have never known!

Comment: @MarkMcClure Sorry, thought I was talking about mathematica!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 *would have never known* unless you read the page to which you linked. It says on top: "Questions about Wolfram Alpha itself are off-topic."

Comment: @user89499 that's assuming a lot about my mobile capabilities (I see no such statement. Sorry for trying to help!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to there being a [WolframAlpha tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha) (as pointed out in the comments), the [about page](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) makes it clear that questions about software that mathematicians use is on topic.  On the other hand, some questions that are on topic might receive more attention elsewhere so it might be worth pointing out that Wolfram Research has recently started a [community forum](http://community.wolfram.com/) with a WolframAlpha group.

Comment: NB. The W|A tag link is to Mathematica.SE, not Mathematics.SE.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I hastily assumed the comment pointed to the WA tag on math.se, thank you for pointing out my error.  I've now edited the link.  By the way, what does NB refer to in this context?

Comment: It stands for the Latin words Nota Bene; in this context, I used it to signify that it was a side remark.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Mark's answer, WolframAlpha questions are also on topic at [WebApps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha).

Comment: So which is it?

Comment: Both - many StackExchange sites have overlapping areas of competence.

Comment: So how do you decide to post here or there (or both)?

Comment: It's which community you think would be a better fit for your question, so probably the way to go is to look at some other questions and see how they compare to yours and how they were answered.  A similar case is how Linux is on topic on both Super User and Unix.SE.  Crossposting is usually frowned upon.