# Unsure of wolfram Alpha Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently asked a question relating to plotting via Wolfram Alpha:

[How can I plot y vs x with multiple terms/variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650427/how-can-i-plot-y-vs-x-with-multiple-terms-variables)

My question was closed as "Off topic" and "missing context". I can sort of guess how someone could find it off topic, but that I still see it as a grey area. I don't get what context is missing though.

I've already read this meta:

[Are questions related to using wolfram alpha on topic?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/are-questions-related-to-using-wolfram-alpha-on-topic)

I searched and found some other questions with Wolfram Alpha tags that seem similar, but were not closed. See below for examples:

[Wolfram alpha plot a sum with 2 unknowns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187044/wolfram-alpha-plot-a-sum-with-2-unknowns)

[How do I plot multi case function in wolfram or geogebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/how-do-i-plot-multi-case-function-in-wolfram-or-geogebra)

So my question is: *Is my question on plotting in Wolfram Alpha truly faulty in comparison, and if so, how?* Perhaps my examples are also worthy of being closed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [the Wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/) for questions that are related to getting their software to do something, unless your question actually has some non-trivial mathematical question. Note that I previously suggested Mathematica SE, but Mark pointed out in the comments that it would be off-topic there as well. And your question is not bad per se, but perhaps the community here prefers not to have (essentially) non-mathematical questions, despite the existence of the [math-software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-software).

Comment: This is simply misinformed. WolframAlpha questions are explicitly off-topic on Mathematica SE, as stated in their [help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and on several of their Meta posts. Here, by contrast, not only is there a [tag:math-software] tag, but the corresponding [help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states that software questions are on topic. I agree, though, that one should focus on mathematics aspects. Perhaps a better suggestion would be to check out the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/).

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Thanks for telling me that. I had assumed (without checking, my mistake) that they would be the right place to go to since one can usually use Mathematica syntax in Wolfram Alpha. I'll edit my post to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is because the users of this site aren't the best answerers of this question. I wonder if you could get a better result by asking this question somewhere on wolfram alpha.